# IIS not showing index page after migration

Tags: iis, iis-7

I am trying to migrate my company intranet site form a Windows 2008 R2 server to a new Windows 2016 server (different computer name).  I exported the application pools and site successfully and imported them into the new server successfully.  I changed the bindings to the new server but one thing I noticed right off the bat was it was telling me the credentials were wrong.  I checked the applicationHost.config file and the username used to connect is the support account but had no domain and the password is not viewable because it looks like it had some kind of encryption or something.

So I changed the settings earlier to my domain\support account and it work and I was able to access everything in IIS properly.  I checked everything I could think of but after the migration, I try to go to my site and it just has the IIS start page on it.  I checked the defaultDocument section in the config and added my index.aspx which is the index page of my site and then I started getting the error 0x800700b7 "Cannot add duplicate collection entry" with no information beyond that.  I checked the config file and there we no duplicate entries anywhere like I was seeing to check online.  It is designed to look at the E:\ drive where I have my intranet folder containing all my pages.

So I said screw it and re-imported the site and applicationhost.config file and again I got a message about the user or password being wrong.  I proceeded to change it back to the domain\support account and got slapped with "Value does not fall within expected range".  I dont know what else to try here, its becoming extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:

- Changed new IIS host to DC which fixed login issue
- Removed Web Deploy 3.6
- Installed Web Deploy 5
- Ran migration through msdeploy commands
- Deleted lines in web.config regarding static content

Everything works now.